# Kafka Consumer messages are not receiving after changing schema registry format

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am new to Kafka and somehow able to run kafka Avro consumer and Producer. Producer is producing the message and i am successfully getting it in consumer. Here is my producer code snippet:

```
static async void AvroProducer()
{
    string bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";
    string schemaRegistryUrl = "Production163:8081"; 
    string topicName = "player";
    string groupName = "avro-generic-example-group";


     var s = (RecordSchema)RecordSchema.Parse(
        @"{
            ""namespace"": ""Confluent.Kafka.Examples.AvroSpecific"",
            ""type"": ""record"",
            ""name"": ""User"",
            ""fields"": [
                {""name"": ""name"", ""type"": ""string""},
                {""name"": ""favorite_number"",  ""type"": [""int"", ""null""]},
                {""name"": ""favorite_color"", ""type"": [""string"", ""null""]}
            ]
          }"
    );

    using (var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig { SchemaRegistryUrl = schemaRegistryUrl }))
    using (var producer =
        new ProducerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(new ProducerConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers })
            .SetKeySerializer(new AsyncAvroSerializer<string>(schemaRegistry))
            .SetValueSerializer(new AsyncAvroSerializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry))
            .Build())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{producer.Name} producing on {topicName}. Enter user names, q to exit.");

        int i = 0;
        string text;
        while ((text = Console.ReadLine()) != "q")
        {
            var record = new GenericRecord(s);
            record.Add("name", text);
            record.Add("favorite_number", i++);
            record.Add("favorite_color", "blue");

            producer.ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<string, GenericRecord> { Key = text, Value = record })
                .ContinueWith(task => task.IsFaulted
                    ? $"error producing message: {task.Exception.Message}"
                    : $"produced to: {task.Result.TopicPartitionOffset}");
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

As you can see in above code i am using a record scheme, But I am trying this scehema:

```
//this is the new schema try
        var s = (RecordSchema)RecordSchema.Parse(
            @"{
                ""type"": ""record"",
                ""name"": ""TestingMsg"",
                ""doc"": ""Sample"",
                ""fields"": [
                  {
                   ""name"": ""key"",
                   ""type"": ""string""
                  },
                  {
                   ""name"": ""Time"",
                   ""type"": ""long""
                  },
                  {
                   ""name"": ""sourceSeconds"",
                   ""type"": ""long""
                  },
                  {
                   ""name"": ""serverT"",
                   ""type"": ""long""
                  },

                  {
                   ""name"": ""statusCode"",
                   ""type"": ""int""
                  }
                ]
                }"
            );
```

The new one which I am trying to use, but it not working as I am not getting messages in consumer.
And here is the consumer :

```
void KafkaReader(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.Log("kafka reader started. . .");
        // Set up your Kafka connection here.

        while (_keepThreadRunning)
        {
            using (CachedSchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig { SchemaRegistryUrl = schemaRegistryUrl }))
            using (IConsumer<string, GenericRecord> consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(new ConsumerConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers, GroupId = groupName })
            //using (IConsumer<string, GenericRecord> consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<string, GenericRecord>(new ConsumerConfig { BootstrapServers = bootstrapServers})
                    .SetKeyDeserializer(new AsyncAvroDeserializer<string>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                    .SetValueDeserializer(new AsyncAvroDeserializer<GenericRecord>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
                    .SetErrorHandler((_, e) => Debug.Log($"Error: {e.Reason}"))
                    .Build())
            {
                Debug.Log("subscribe" );
                consumer.Subscribe(topicName);


                while (true)
                {
                    ConsumeResult<string, GenericRecord> consumeResult = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);//TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50000)//new TimeSpan(0,0,1)

                    _stringsReceived.Enqueue(consumeResult.Value.ToString());


                    if (consumeResult != null)
                    {
                        Debug.Log($"Key: {consumeResult.Message.Key}\nValue: {consumeResult.Value}");


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("consumer Result is null");
                    }

                    //yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
                }
            }


        }

        GetComponent<KafkaServerConfigUI>().KafkaDisconnected();

        // Disconnect and clean up your connection here.


    }
```

Remember I just running the default apache Kafka registry using a batch file.

```
D:\ApachKafka\confluent\confluent-5.2.1\bin\windows\schema-registry-start.bat D:\ApachKafka\confluent\confluent-5.2.1\etc\schema-registry\schema-registry.properties
```

What i am doing wrong? Do i need to register the schema to anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making any change or using new schema, you have to register the schema. I was missing this thing therefore I was not getting the messages in consumer. Here is the [**short python script**](https://gist.github.com/aseigneurin/5730c07b4136a84acb5aeec42310312c) that help you to register the schema.

Using the [**script**](https://gist.github.com/aseigneurin/5730c07b4136a84acb5aeec42310312c), You have to provide the URL of the Schema Registry (starting with http://, not just a hostname and port), the topic for which the schema should be registered, and the path to the schema.

Here is the way i registrer my schema

[image]

Thank to Ref: [*Avro and Schema registry*](https://aseigneurin.github.io/2018/08/02/kafka-tutorial-4-avro-and-schema-registry.html)

Answer (score 0):

I know you have answer for this. Here is my suggestion to avoid running python script for each schema update.

You can use schema-registry-ui.

In a nut-shell the schema-registry-ui provides
- Exploring and searching schemas
- Avro evolution compatibility checks
- New schema registration
- Avro + Table schema views
- Displaying CURL commands

#### How to get it

```
git clone https://github.com/Landoop/schema-registry-ui.git
cd schema-registry-ui
npm install -g bower
npm install
http-server .
```

#### Demo

```
http://schema-registry-ui.landoop.com/
```

Or docker images are available. If you can opt for license, try confluent control center, which provides even more options.